# Table storage: $top broken after migration to Azure 1.8 SDK?

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I use Data Services to query Azure Tables.

In 1.7 version of SDK any query to a table that had top > 1000 would be split into several queries and correct top was calculated for each one. For example this is what I see in Fiddler when I query a table for 1500 rows (first request for 1000 rows, second for 500 rows):

```
200 HTTPS   foo.table.core.windows.net  /Foo()?$top=1500
200 HTTPS   foo.table.core.windows.net  /Foo()?$top=500&NextPartitionKey=1!28!dGVzdGFjY291bnRfMzMxZTZkNTk-&NextRowKey=1!0!
```

After migration to 1.8 SDK the first query uses top 1500 and 400 is returned:

```
400 HTTPS   foo.table.core.windows.net  /Foo()?$top=1500
```

Is this a breaking change in Azure SDK? Do I need to calculate $top value myself based on the number of rows returned or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Can you share the code? I tried using it with Storage Client Library version 1.7 and got the 400 error if I try and fetch more than 1500. I would like to take your code and try using it.

Comment: I found the code that was doing this in 1.7 and it is gone in 1.8 :(